# Configuring R with QGIS - scripts not running/displaying, settings checked

Tags: qgis, r

I have installed R scripts processing plugin but got the following error message when I run the test script:

"This algorithm requires R to be run. Unfortunately, it seems that R is not installed in your system, or it is not correctly configured to be used from QGIS"
I solved this by selecting the 'use 64-bit' option as my installation of R is 64-bit. I ran the test_sf example script which worked, however when I try and run any other script, nothing happens, progress stays at 0% and nothing appears in the log. I am running the simple following script just to try to open and view a shapefile:

```
library(rgdal)
library(leaflet)

shapefile_path <- "C:/my/file/path/myfile.shp"


shapefile <- readOGR(dsn = shapefile_path, layer = basename(shapefile_path), verbose = TRUE)

#plotting the shapefile:

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = shapefile, fillOpacity = 0.5, color = "red", popup = ~as.character(shapefile$ID))
```

Nothing happens, the dialogue box appears, but status stays at 0%.

I tried to also use the 'scatterplot' example script which runs, however the layers won't load. The dialogue box says "Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Scatterplot' finished
HTML output has been generated by this algorithm.
Open the results dialog to check it."

However nothing loads. I've now spent 2 hours reading various help pages and even asking Chat GPT and tried all suggestions, e.g: reinstalling the plugin, checking settings in 'Providers' in the processing toolbox etc, nothing is working.

The R settings in QGIS look like this:

[image: R settings QGIS]

Comment: Can you show us the settings?

Comment: Have now added the settings to the original post, thanks.